# Get insert/update/delete operation data into the MongoDD oplog.rs

Tags: mongodb

I am running the mongodb as windows service(link : http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows/)

```
    Config File :

    dbpath=D:\mongodb\data

    logpath=D:\mongodb\log\mongo.log

    diaglog=3

    replSet=rs0

    Created the replication set for my local database

    >var config = {_id: "rs0", members: [{_id: 0, host: "127.0.0.1:27017"}]}

    >rs.initiate(config)

    > rs.conf()

    {
            "_id" : "rs0",

            "version" : 1,

            "members" : [

                    {
                            "_id" : 0,
                            "host" : "127.0.0.1:27017"
                    }
            ]
    }

    Now testing the data in the oplog.rs

    rs0:PRIMARY> use local


    rs0:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.find()

    { 
"ts" : Timestamp(1409719824, 1),

 "h" : NumberLong(0), 

"v" : 2,

 "op" : "n",

 "ns" : "",

 "o" : { "msg" : "initiating set" }

 }
```

I got above result when run the command for the first time.

Inserted the new document to the local database and run the db.oplog.rs.find() command, still it shows the same result.

Please let me know steps to get the insert/update/delete operation data into the oplog.rs

Comment: You don't want to do that. This is a reserved collection so you shouldn't be touching it other than for reads.

Comment: @NeilLunn is right. And you most likely don't see any entries because all nodes of the replica set have applied the operation in question. Start a multi node replset, tear down one of the secondaries and do a write operation. This should show in the oplog.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I created new database and inserted the data, got reflected in oplog.rs which was under local db.